# How to know the encoding of a file in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

Does anybody know how to get the encoding of a file in Python. I know that you can use the codecs module to open a file with a specific encoding but you have to know it in advance.

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("file.txt", "r", "utf-8")
```

Is there a way to detect automatically which encoding is used for a file?

Thanks in advance

Edit: 
Thanks everybody for very interesting answsers. You may also be interested by http://whatismyencoding.com/ which is based on chardet (more over the site is powered by bottle python framework)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no 'correct' way to determine the encoding of a file by looking at the file itself. This is a universal problem, not limited to python or any particular file system.

If you're reading an XML file, the first line in the file *might* give you a hint of what the encoding is.

Otherwise, you will have to use some heuristics-based  approach like [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) (one of the solutions given in other answers) which tries to guess the encoding by examining the data in the file in raw byte format. If you're on Windows, I believe the Windows API also exposes methods to try and guess the encoding based on the data in the file.

Answer (score 8):

You may use BOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to detect the encoding, or try this library:

https://github.com/chardet/chardet

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small snippet to help you to guess the encoding. It guesses between latin1 and utf8 quite good. It converts a byte string to a unicode string.

```
# Attention: Order of encoding_guess_list is import. Example: "latin1" always succeeds.
encoding_guess_list=['utf8', 'latin1']
def try_unicode(string, errors='strict'):
    if isinstance(string, unicode):
        return string
    assert isinstance(string, str), repr(string)
    for enc in encoding_guess_list:
        try:
            return string.decode(enc, errors)
        except UnicodeError, exc:
            continue
    raise UnicodeError('Failed to convert %r' % string)
def test_try_unicode():
    for start, should in [
        ('\xfc', u'ü'),
        ('\xc3\xbc', u'ü'),
        ('\xbb', u'\xbb'), # postgres/psycopg2 latin1: RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
        ]:
        result=try_unicode(start, errors='strict')
        if not result==should:
            raise Exception(u'Error: start=%r should=%r result=%r' % (
                    start, should, result))
```

Comment: I simplified and adapted this a bit, using merely a .decode() in a try-except which breaks out upon (1) a successful conversion, or (2) after exhausting the encoding_guess_list.  If the end was a fail, then I apply a different .decode() with the errors set to 'replace' instead of 'strict'.

Answer (score 4):

There is [Unicode Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit) from [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which uses [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) but adds a couple of extra features.

It tries to read the encoding from inside XML or HTML files. Then it tries looking for a BOM or something like that at the start of the file. If it can't do that, it makes use of [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Line by line detecting encoding if input and then convert it into UTF-8
Suitable for look at logs with mixed encoding (i.e. from mail systems)

"""

import sys
import chardet

while 1:
        l = sys.stdin.readline()
        e = chardet.detect(l)

        u = None
        try:
                if e['confidence'] > 0.3:
                        u = unicode(l, e['encoding'])
        except:
                pass

        if u:
                print u,
        else:
                print l,
```

Comment: Encoding can't always be detected in intermediate lines (e.g. BOM). And there're no interesting high level cases where encoding changes mid-file.