# python read text: 're -->鈥檙e

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am reading a text file with the following sentence:

"So whether you’re talking about a Walmart
or an IKEA or a Zara,
you are really interested in keeping the
cost low, keeping the process very
efficient."

my code:

```
files = "*.txt"
for pathname in glob.glob(files):
    with open(pathname,'r') as singlefile:
        data = "".join(singlefile.readlines())
        data = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\n", " ", data)
        data = re.sub(r",\n", ", ", data)
        print data
```

result I got is

"So whether you鈥檙e talking about a Walmart or an IKEA or a Zara, you are really interested in keeping the cost low, keeping the process very efficient.
That gives us operational excellence."

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the encoding. It looks like the ' is not recognized.

Comment: You need to read the file using the encoding it was saved as.

Comment: how do I know its encoding?

Comment: Either you find out from the person who gave you the file, or you guess.

Comment: P.S. It would help if you `print repr(data)` so we can see the exact bytes.

Comment: It is the encoding problem and "utf-8" will read it correctly. codecs.open("file.txt", "r", "utf-8")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the encoding right (for this also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144815/how-to-know-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-python), where they also describe an encoding guess list - which is a neat idea), it works just fine. I have tried it with:

```
import re

with open("words.txt",'r') as singlefile:
    data = "".join(singlefile.readlines())
    data = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\n", " ", data)
    data = re.sub(r",\n", ", ", data)
    print data
```

And in the file "words.txt" is this:

```
 So whether you’re talking about a Walmart or an IKEA or a Zara, you are really interested in keeping the cost low, keeping the process very efficient.
```

This is the output:

```
>>> runfile('E:/programmierung/python/spielwiese/test.py', wdir=r'E:/programmierung/python/spielwiese')
So whether you’re talking about a Walmart or an IKEA or a Zara, you are really interested in keeping the cost low, keeping the process very efficient.
>>>
```